# Checkout single folder in Git

Tags: git

I've cloned my repository via `git clone`, and now I want to checkout a folder.

Source folder: `/opt/XYZ/foldertochecout`

and it should be checked out to

```
/var/www/foldertochecout
```

Is that possible and how?

Comment: No sorry thats not the answer of my question ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) allows specifying a path after the `--` argument separator. So for example, this will check out only that directory:

```
git checkout HEAD -- opt/XYZ/foldertocheckout
```

(assuming that `opt/XYZ/` is *also* part of your repository—although that seems a bit unlikely and `XYZ` is probably your repository directory)

Comment: this is the reopository: /opt/XYZ and the foldertochecout is a subfolder in the repository. and I want to check it out in the apach folder under /var/www/destination